# How to give a default value in adonis model. i am using adonis typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, orm, adonis.js

Here i am using adonis framework of node.js in which it uses their own orm (lucid orm). I am stuck how to give a default value here for a date i using a publishedDate field in code.I want to store a current date in YYYY-MM-DD format

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import { BaseModel, BelongsTo, belongsTo, column } from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm'
import User from './User'

export default class Post extends BaseModel {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  public id: number

  @column()
  public title: string

  @column()
  public description: string | null

  @column()
  public publishedDate: Date

  @column()
  public userId: number

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  public createdAt: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  public updatedAt: DateTime

  @belongsTo(() => User, {
    foreignKey: 'userId',
  })
  public posts: BelongsTo<typeof User>
}
```

Comment: use ```@column.date() ``` instead of ```@column.dateTime()```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign default values in your table migrations, example

```
table.date('published_date').defaultTo(#YOUR DATE#)
```

However, I'm not sure if you can store it in YYYY-MM-DD format. You can play around and see if it works. If it does not work, then you have to store your date as ISO datetime string and use the `@computed` decorator to format your date.

https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/orm/decorators#computed

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
table.timestamp('created_at', { useTz: true }).defaultTo(this.now())
table.timestamp('updated_at', { useTz: true }).defaultTo(this.now())
```